# Solving sudoku in Ada

Tags: ada

This is mostly solved now thank you

procedure Sudoku is
-- Set Array Types
type arr is array(1..9,1..9) of integer;
type solutions is array(integer range <>)of integer;

```
-- Declare Variable Types   
infp : File_Type;  
fileName : string(1..50);
fromFile : string(1..9);
last: natural;
num : arr;
j : integer;

--
--Function to check if board is full
--
function isTrue(board : arr) return boolean is
    --Variable Declaration
    numCheck : integer;
    
    begin
        for x in 1..9 loop
            for y in 1..9 loop
                if board(x,y) /= 0 then
                    numCheck := board(x,y);
                    
                    for k in 1..9 loop
                        if numCheck = board(x,k) and k /= y then
                            put_line("Unsolvable Puzzle");
                            return false;
                        end if;
                        if numCheck = board(k,y) and k /= x then
                            put(x);
                            put(y);
                            put_line("Unsolvable Puzzle");
                            return false;
                        end if;
                        
                    end loop;
                end if;
            end loop;
        end loop;
    
        return true;
    
    end isTrue;
```

Comment: _Is_ there a `begin` in the procedure? NB by not showing the whole code you have wasted a lot of time, yours and your readers

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your revised approach.

Comment: You have an extra `begin null;` at line 14 - delete it (I know someone suggested it, that was before you showed us all these new declarations). You should probably delete lines 43, 44, 45 - it doesn’t make sense to have 2 procedures with the same name at the same level in the same file (if at all). Presumably you have more to come after line 97?

Comment: Adding line numbers to your code makes it more difficult for people to copy and compile it. If you need to refer to a line by number, add a comment to the code like `-- line 42`.

Answer (score 2):

A procedure looks like

```
procedure Proc (params) is
   {declarations}
begin
   {statements}
end Proc;
```

which is a pattern you use without problem in the nested procedures; but it applies just the same to the outer `sudoku` procedures. Note that `{declarations}` can include nested subprograms.

At line 43 you `end` the first `sudoku`, which began at line 5, without any

```
begin
   {statements}
```

and at line 44 you start a second `sudoku`, which you `end` at line 124, again without any

```
begin
   {statements}
```

So that makes two outer-level procedures in the same file, which is something that GNAT does not support out of the box.

In any case, I think you probably only want one `sudoku` procedure, so you need to merge the two declarative regions and write a body that calls the nested procedures as appropriate (something I can’t help you with).